# Getting Windows domain username in correct case (to match Active Directory)

Tags: windows, perl, active-directory

How can I sensibly get a Windows 7 user's username, but in the case that it's stored in the Active Directory domain (such as `BillyBird`), not using whatever case the user happened to type it when logging in (probably `billybird`, but could even be something like `bILlYbIRd`)?

This is in Perl, but since it's interacting with the operating system, solutions in other languages may be translatable.

I've tried these and they don't work; they all return the username in the case it was typed by the user when logging in*:

- `getlogin`
- `Win32::LoginName`
- `$ENV{USERNAME}`
- `Win32::OLE->new('WScript.Network')->UserName`
- `Win32API::Net::UserGetInfo`

I have come up with a couple of bad ways of getting the right value. I'll post those as answers and hope that somebody else has a better one. Thanks.

* At least they do some of the time. For some users it alternates each time they log in between giving the as-typed and the as-AD values, but in all cases the above methods all agree with each other and `%USERNAME%`.

Comment: Why? Active Directory won't care about case when you search for a username

Comment: Ah the eternal *"they don't work"*! Would you explain what is wrong with each of these, please?

Comment: Have you thought of parsing the output of `wmic useraccount get name`? It will be simple to find the relevant username that is a case-independent match for `$ENV{USERNAME}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I need the username in the correct case for making an SSH connection to a Unix server. (I didn't mention that cos I didn't think why was relevant to the question. Apologies if it is.)

Comment: I would probably do an ldap search using `Net::LDAP` for the username `bIlLyBiRd` and see what value the returned accounts `samaccountname` has

Comment: @Borodin Sorry if it isn't clear. The rest of the sentence, following the 3 words you quote is “they return the username in the case it was typed”. What more information do you need?

Comment: @Borodin Thanks. I wasn't aware of `wmic` before now.

Comment: @Smylers: Oh, so you're saying they *all* produce the same value--the value actually typed to log in?

Comment: @Borodin Yes. I've rephrased that bit of the question which hopefully makes that clearer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I looked at `Net::LDAP` but it seems to require a username and password to query Active Directory, which is hassle to have to provide securely, especially when the information is available by other means.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the right value, but involves fetching the list of all domain users over the network and iterating over them looking for a case-insensitive match, which seems excessive just for returning something about the current user:

```
use v5.16;
use Win32::NetAdmin qw<GetDomainController GetUsers FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT>;
my $comparable_username = fc getlogin;
GetDomainController('', '', my $domain_controller);
GetUsers($domain_controller, FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT, \my @all_username);
my $username;
for (@all_username)
{
  if (fc eq $comparable_username)
  {
    $username = $_;
    last;
  }
}
```

Comment: `use List::Util; my $username = first {fc eq $comparable_username} @all_username;`

Comment: @tjd Good idea — that's much better way of writing this. But it still seems a suboptimal thing to have to be doing in the first place, checking through every user one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thought about using `wmic` put into practice

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

say username();

sub username {
    for ( `wmic useraccount get name` ) {
        return $1 if /\A($ENV{USERNAME})\s*\z/i;
    }
    return;
}
```

---

#### Update

To prevent `wmic` from fetching the full user name list, you can use the `LIKE` operator in a `WHERE` cal

```
sub username {
    my @user = `wmic UserAccount WHERE ( name LIKE '$ENV{username}' ) GET name`;
    return unless $user[1] =~ /\S/;
    $user[1] =~ s/\s+\z//r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to make that `wmic useraccount where LocalAccount="FALSE" get name` to avoid picking up a local non-domain account with different casing. It's a shame it still involves getting and searching through all users. Unfortunately even `where Name="$ENV{USERNAME}"` returns `name` as supplied, not the way it's returned if I don't request a specific name.

Comment: @Smylers: I've added an update to my solution which may help you

Comment: Thanks. `LIKE` works even though `=` doesn't. Unfortunately it's still very slow though, taking about 2 s. Obviously some of that is the overhead of running an external command, but it's about 8-times slower than running and parsing `NET USER` (~0.25 s).

Comment: @Smylers: How about creating a hash during initialisation of your program that maps the lower-case version of all user names to their "official" versions? Thereafter the operation is just `$real_user{lc $ENV{USERNAME}}`

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible solution; it gets the username in the right case:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw<capturex>;
my $username;
foreach (capturex qw<NET USER /DOMAIN>, getlogin)
{
  if (/^User name\s*(\S+)$/)
  {
    $username = $1;
    last;
  }
}
```

However it involves running an external system command to parse its output (which is relatively slow), and relies on that output always being in English. An alternative solution that used an API for directly looking up whatever the `NET USER` command is doing would be superior to this one.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please don't use answers as a way to add more information. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @simbabque: This *is* an answer, in that it does yield the desired output. It has its pros and cons, so there may be better answers out there (and I'm hoping somebody will provide one), but that doesn't make this not an answer, and it may be the best answer in some circumstances. By posting it as a separate answer, users can vote on this compared with alternative answers (which have different pros and cons).